# how to resolve __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'name', 'email', 'password', and 'age'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

y'all i have flask backend react frontend when i tried to post some infos to data i get a few error. let me explain you.

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.json.get('name', None)
        email = request.json.get('email', None)
        age = request.json.get('age')
        password = request.json.get('password', None)
        if not name:
            return "Missing Name"
        if not email:
            return "Missing Email"
        if not password:
            return "Missing Password"
        if not age:
            return "Missing Age"
        hashed = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password.encode('utf-8'))
        session["2o1£21ıoj2£#31ı12k3130o210*321"] = name
        addUser = User(name=name, email=email, password=hashed, age=age)

        create_access_token(identity=name)
        db.session.add(addUser)
        db.session.commit()
        return "user created"
```

```
@app.route("/profile", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.json.get('post', None)
        if not post:
            return "Write Something"
        addPost = User(post=post)
        db.session.add(addPost)
        db.session.commit()
        return "Posted"
    return "Posted"
```

on "/register" everything is ok ,there is no problem but i want to use User table on "/profile". When i tried this i get **"**init**() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'name', 'email', 'password', and 'age'"** this error
how can i to this?

Comment: Are you sure you want `addPost` to be a `User` object?  It sounds like maybe it wants to be a `Post` object.

Comment: if you want to say create a new table called `Post`  i want to all data's been same table. @Samwise

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at with "all data's been same table" -- the crux of the matter is that a `User` entry needs to have those four pieces of data, and you aren't providing them.